# How do I set a Dijit splitter in a BorderContainer to close all the way?

Tags: layout, dojo, splitter

Does anyone know what property to set on a BorderContainer to allow the user to move the splitter all the way left or right to completely hide sections of your page?

The demo allows you to close the center panel completely by dragging right, but it leaves a gap when dragging left:

https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.8/dijit_layout/demo/appLayout.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the minSize of the left ContenPane in **data-dojo-props** where the splitter is enabled ! But set it to at least 1 ! Setting it to 0 will not work ! It should look something like that: **data-dojo-props="minSize:1, splitter: true"**
Here is the necessary code regarding the link i edited in your post (your link was broken):

```
<div id="leftCol" class="edgePanel" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" 
data-dojo-props="minSize:1,region: 'left', splitter: true">Sidebar content (left)</div>
```

Comment: It works!  The only problem is that now if you drag the splitter all the way left, leave it, and drag it back, the splitter somehow moves one width into the left-hand content pane.  I guess that's just a Dojo bug. Thanks.